# UICollectionView scrolling slow at first, dealing with images

Tags: ios, image, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is going to seem like very poor programming practice, but I don't know how to implement any other routines.

I have a `UICollectionView` that manages 3 x 20 cells, where each cell displays a different image.  Originally, my custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass (`StoneCell`) is defaulted with an image `StoneLocked.png`.  So all 60 cells start out with that image.  However, eventually, all of the cells will display a "stone" with a different image.  I wanted to test out the look of that by loading each different image into one of the 60 cells.  Here is what I wrote.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"stoneCell";

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //UICollectionViewCell* regular;
    NSMutableArray *sA = [self.stoneArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSNumber *stoneNum = [sA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    StoneCell *cell = (StoneCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([stoneNum integerValue] == 0) {
        [cell.stone setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Banana.png"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.stone setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else if ([stoneNum integerValue] == 1) {
        [cell.stone setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Flamingo.png"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.stone setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else if {
        // IMAGE NOW 58 MORE if-else STATEMENTS LIKE THE ABOVE 2.
    }

    cell.stone.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    cell.stone.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [cell addSubview:cell.stone];
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    return cell; 
}
```

Initially when I scroll through the view, all the images are loaded and displayed correctly.  However, the scrolling is very choppy.

When I reach the bottom of the screen, and then scroll freely up and down throughout the view, everything is fine and working the way it should.

How can I make it so that right from the get-go, the choppiness is non-existent?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I decided to lazy load the images ahead of time during the `viewDidLoad` stage.  Stored those images in an array, then just used their index when I needed them.  Much better scrolling response, smooth and crisp.

Comment: You should also move your image loading into a background queue, otherwise the app may still seem laggy to users.